# Creating a Perforce form trigger to change default description with multi-lines

Tags: bash, perforce

I have a Linux based Perforce server that I'm attempting to create a p4 trigger that modifies the changelist description for all users using a template. Single lines are easy, but as soon as I needed to have multi-line, I ran into problems, and found that using ANSI-C Quoting was the only way to add newlines.

I have it "mostly" working, but dont quite understand bash well enough to know what is wrong.

I wanted the script to live in the depot, so it could easily be adjusted without having p4 admin access, so i committed the script into the depot and enable the trigger like this:

```
Triggers:
    desc-out form-out change "sh %//tools/main/Perforce/defaultChangelist.sh% out %formfile%"
```

The script code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

opt="end"

if [ "$1" = "out" ]; then
    opt="out"
fi

if [ "$1" = "in" ]; then
    opt="in"
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    opt="end"
fi

mydesc=$'Jira Ticket: High level summary\n\t- Detailed change #1\n\t- Detailed change #2'

case $opt in
    "out")
        sed -i "s|<enter description here>|$mydesc|" "$2"
        ;;
    "in")
        grep -qF "$mydesc" "$2"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            exit 0
        else
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

mydesc=""
opt=""
```

This mostly works, but seems to be inserting a $ into the first character of the description, and looks like this:

```
$Jira Ticket: High level summary
    - Detailed change #1
    - Detailed change #2
```

How can i remove that first dollar sign in the output?

Comment: Any time you find an unexpected string in the output of a command, one of the first things to look for is whether or not that unexpected string exists inside your command. What happens if you change `mydesc=$'Jira Ticket:` to `mydesc='Jira Ticket:`?

Answer (score 2):

The construct `$'...'` has no specific meaning in a POSIX shell. The `$` is taken literally.

You would have to run your program by `bash`. That is you have to change the invocation to

```
desc-out form-out change "bash %//tools/main/Perforce/defaultChangelist.sh% out %formfile%"
```

**UPDATE** (Clarification suggested in a comment):

If you have a script X and run it as

```
P X
```

where P is i.e. a shell or interpreter (sh, bash, perl ruby), P is used to process X, and X should reasonably be written in the programming language implemented by P. Therefore

```
sh script.sh
```

executes `script.sh` as a POSIX shell script, while

```
bash script.sh
```

executes it as bash script. In both cases, no PATH search is done for locating script.sh, and script.sh must have read permission.

If you write the invocation simply as

```
script.sh
```

the executing process (Perforce, or some shell) is supposed to honour the #! line of script.sh to find out, which shell (or interpreter) needs to be executed to run the script. script.sh must have read and execute permission, and a PATH search is done for locating it.

If in the latter case the #! line is missing, it is up to the executing process how the script is run. A common convention is to use a POSIX shell (sh, dash,...) to run script.sh in that case, but not all shells are honouring this convention.

Comment: Seems I am unable to run it as bash, and only POSIX. So I need to find another solution to inserting newlines..

Comment: @feitz: How about using `printf` to generate the string?